# Access-Control-Request-Headers passing parameter name instead of value in published version

Tags: flutter, dart, iis, flutter-web

I just published my first Flutter project on a local VM. Went to test that everything was working and the API connections are not passing correctly. When testing back on my local host it works just fine and am not sure why it is changing.

I am looking under the networking tab in development view to see the code of the connection return.

Published Version:

```js
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin,apikey,customer_id
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
```

Debug Version:

```js
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
APIKey: 6ar872bh83f46a643a1ea385c2130
Connection: keep-alive
customer_id: KDCNOR
Host: 65.254.144.50:5114
Referer: http://localhost:58392/
```

Method to API call and adding headers:

```js
Future<CustomerJson?> CustomerCall(String CustomerID, String APIKey) async {
  var headers = {'APIKey': APIKey, 'customer_id': CustomerID, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'};
  var request = http.Request(
      'GET', Uri.parse('http://65.254.144.50:5114/Customers/customer_id'));

  request.headers.addAll(headers);

  final response = await request.send();
  final String respStr = await response.stream.bytesToString();

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    CustomerJson _customer = CustomerJson.fromJson(
        jsonDecode(respStr.toString()) as Map<String, dynamic>);
    return _customer;
  } else {
    print(response.reasonPhrase);
  }
}
```

as you can see the Access-Control-Request-Header in the published version just seems to have the parameter names but not the value and the debug version has no Access-Control-Request-Headers field and just implements them directly. Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Comment: Are you sure that "Published version" is not Preflight request: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request? Could it be that your API allows cross-origin access?

Comment: @user18309290 I am not fully sure how to check if it is a preflight request or how to fix it if it is one. As for the API allowing cross origin access, is it not supposed to?

Comment: There is an example in the link. The method is OPTIONS and the actual method is in Access-Control-Request-Method like in your "Published version".

Comment: I see now that there are in fact 2 requests going out. the first one sends the info but it comes back as a 401 error so my guess is something is going on with the APIkey getting passed

Comment: @user18309290 is there a way to disable Preflight requests? it does not seem that the debug version is sending one and that might be the issue

Comment: No. Your server needs to allow cross-origin access in order to continue. In this link, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS, the whole process is described in detailed.